# Mariabackup in production queries are very slow

Tags: backup, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I'm using mariabackup to create a new slave from our master server and after I ran the command my database is getting stuck or queries are processed very low.

VM 64GB 32 core

I'm using NFS storage for backup and db version is MariaDB 10.4

Queries are blocked in status: updating or statistics and after 5-10 seconds are processed.

Another note is I recently upgraded from 10.2 to 10.4 and insert/update queries are processed very low. between 1 and 3 seconds.

Mariabackup command:

**mariabackup --backup --target-dir /backup-db --user xx --password yy**

My cnf:

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size=24G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=24
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_buffer_size=4G
innodb_log_file_size=8G

#innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_write_io_threads=64
innodb_read_io_threads=64
innodb_thread_concurrency=64

character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
interactive_timeout = 28800
wait_timeout = 28800
connect_timeout = 30
net_read_timeout = 60
net_write_timeout = 60
innodb_rollback_on_timeout = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120
server_id=2001
sql_mode=""
performance_schema=0
ft_min_word_len=2
local-infile=0
max_connections=5000
max_user_connections=5000
key_buffer_size = 512M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
read_buffer_size = 1M
table_open_cache = 5000
thread_cache_size = 512
tmp_table_size = 256M
max_heap_table_size = 128M
# Is set to maximum - https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/es/system-variables/max_allowed_packet/
max_allowed_packet = 1073741824
net_buffer_length = 16384
read_rnd_buffer_size = 786432
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
query_cache_limit = 24M
query_cache_size = 256M
query_cache_type = 1
query_prealloc_size = 2457600
query_alloc_block_size = 1638400
transaction_alloc_block_size = 8192
transaction_prealloc_size = 4096
max_write_lock_count = 8
external-locking = FALSE
open_files_limit = 50000
expire_logs_days = 1
max_binlog_size = 1024M
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/mysql_err.log
log_bin=/var/lib/mysql/mysql_bin.log

[mysqld_safe]
[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 1073741824

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 384M
sort_buffer = 384M
read_buffer = 256M
write_buffer = 256M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 384M
sort_buffer = 384M
read_buffer = 256M
write_buffer = 256M

#### Per connection configuration ####
sort_buffer_size = 1M
join_buffer_size = 1M
thread_stack = 192K
```

Comment: Are you saying it is slow/stuck **while** you are running mariabackup, or are you saying it continues to be slow/stuck **after** mariabackup has completed?

Comment: Was NFS used when you had 10.2?

Comment: NFS is used just for backup. is a NFS storage mounted on db server using another storage to not affect the iops on the current machine

Answer (score 0):

```
innodb_log_buffer_size=4G --> 32M
key_buffer_size = 512M  --> 20M assuming you have no MyISAM tables
query_cache_size = 256M  00> 0
query_cache_type = 1  --> 0
```

Please show us

- The slow queries.
- `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables in those queries
- `SHOW TABLE STATUS` for the tables in those queries
- `EXPLAIN ...` if that version allows Explain on non-Selects.

If you weren't using NFS before, I would add it to the list of suspects.

Comment: thanks for answer Rick. can you give me more details why innodb_log_buffer_size must be 32M? is not too low?

Comment: another is note is that while on 10.2 we used bare-metal machine and now with 10.4 is a VM.

Comment: @raduparaleste the log_buffer is just a ram buffer for streaming transaction details to disk.  Making it huge takes away from other things (eg, buffer_pool) that do need more RAM.

Comment: "1 to 3 seconds" -- what was the speed on the other machine?  Do you have any way to measure the I/O activity?  Was it previously on NFS or SSD?

Comment: regarding log_buffer make sense. thanks. on the other machine with 10.2 the insert speed is up to 50ms. ssd. I used NFS just for backup in order to create the replica server.